# Is the Raspberry Pi 5 Power Supply Compatible to the Pi 4

Tags: hardware, power, power-supply

I need a new power supply for my Pi 4.

Somewhen I will use a Raspberry Pi 5, but it needs the quite special Raspberry Pi 5 power supply.

Is the Raspberry Pi 5 PSU (officially) compatible to the Raspberry Pi 4?

To make this clear: I know, the Voltage is the same, but at least early Pi 4 like mine, hat a quirk in the power delivery support. So this question is more about "will the protocol allow the Pi 4 to work without changing the hardware" and less about "is the voltage the same and the max. current enough".

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

The problems with early Pi4 was with e-marked cables.